# Plot the length of text for two categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Imagine I have the following dataframe

```
         text                 category
0     "The cat runs..."          1
1     "Why is that..."           2
2     "The job is very..."       2
3     "For some reason..."       2
4     "The level of..."          1
```

I would like to make two separate plots that for each category, 1 and 2, that shows the length of the number of words for each observations found in that category

So far, I have tried to split the data frame for each category (category1 and category2) and apply the following for, let's say category 1:

```
 x = category1['text'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split()))
```

My plan was to make a barplot for this `x`

But for some reason I get the error that: `'Series' object is not callable`

Anyone that has a different or better approach?

Comment: `x = category1['text'].str.split().str.len()`?

Comment: The question lacks focus because it is two questions (1) how to get the word count of a sentence and (2) how to plot based on a group. In the future, create two questions.